# How to use interp1 with NaN values?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, warnings, nan

I have a matrix of dimensions (`4000x4`) (lets call this `A`) that contains data which is plotted on the y axis. I also have a separate matrix that is (4000,1) (lets call this `B`) that contains data plotted on the x axis. When plotted this produces 4 separate line graphs one for each column.

In matrix `A` there are many Nan (not a number) values in every column. I want to replace the Nan values with interpolated values. I have written a code that does this but it issues a warning. This is the code that I have written.

```
A(:,:)=interp1(B,A,B(:,1),'cubic');
```

When I run this code a warning is issued due to the data not being evenly spaced. Also this code is quite slow. This code is quite slow for the job. I want to modify the code so that no warning is issued and only values that are Nan are interpolated rather than interpolating every values (as this code does). I need to do this to speed up the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you just have `NaN`'s in your data vector `A` and your x-axis vector `B` is alright?

For example take a equidistant time vector `t` from 1 to 100. And a data vector `x` where every tenth value is `NaN`:

```
% example data
t = 1:100;
x = 100*t-t.^2;
x(10:10:end) = NaN;
```

Now take all values of `t` and `x` which are not `NaN` as sample points and interpolate them with the complete time-vector `t` as query points.

```
xi = interp1( t(~isnan(x)), x(~isnan(x)) , t, 'cubic');
```

---

or a little more complex for your case:

```
% example data
B = (1:4000)';                 % 4000x1 double
A = repmat(1000*B-B.^2,4,1)';  % 4000x4 double
A(randi(400,40,1)) = NaN;      % random NaNs in your data matrix

Ai = zeros(size(A));
for ii = 1:size(A,2);
    tmp = A(:,ii);
    Ai(:,ii) = interp1( B(~isnan(tmp)) , tmp(~isnan(tmp)) , B, 'cubic');
end
```

and the loopless alternative:

```
C  = num2cell(A,1);
Ci = cellfun(@(x) interp1( B(~isnan(x)), x(~isnan(x)), B,'cubic'), C, ...   
             'UniformOutput',false);
Ci = cell2mat(Ci')';
```

Comment: I made a mistake earlier. A is a matrix whereas B is actually a vector. There are only Nan values in A but no nan values in B. There is a relation in the values of A but only to values that are close to each other. So value (1,1) has a close relation to (1:100,1) but almost no relation with (2000,1). So would the cubic method be the best choice here.

Comment: well than just swap `A` with `B` - even the value `A(1,1)` is unrelated to `A(100,1)` as `interp1` just does piecewise interpolation and `'cubic'` just involves 4 subsequent values. Maybe you're looking for `polyfit`?

Comment: @user3101914: have a look at my last edit. I think `interp1` is the right way to go. I'd consider `'linear'` instead of `'cubic'` - just try out what fits your needs better.

Comment: Thanks for the code that now works. However I still get a warning as follows:Warning: Columns of data containing NaN values have been ignored during interpolation. 
> In interp1>Interp1DStripNaN at 239
  In interp1 at 176 Why do I get this and how can I remove it?

Comment: For my example data the code works absolutely fine. I'd guess the problem is My code is for a 4x100 data matrix, and not for 100x4 or 4000x4 like for your case. Please transpose your data matrix `A=A'` and try again. It should definetely work. If not, please try my example data and have a look if that is working. If just the example work, please upload your data and I have a look at it.

Comment: Wait! I have edited my example for the same dimensions like your data. You don't need to transpose something anymore!

Answer (score 0):

use the extrapolation option.
here an example from matlab help

without extrapolation
vq2 = interp1(x,v,xq,'linear')
vq2 =  NaN   NaN    14   NaN   NaN

with linear extrapolation
vq3 = interp1(x,v,xq,'linear','extrap')
vq3 = 8    10    14     4     2